# Markov model's first step analysis

Tags: conditional-probability, markov-process

Following is the problem:

*You have five fair coins. You toss them all so that they randomly fall heads or tails. Those that fall tails in the first toss you pick up and toss. You toss again those that show tails after the second toss and so on, until all show heads. Let X be the number of coins involved. in the last toss. Find P(X=1)*

Solution: So first, let the state bee seen as the **number of tails** going from 5 to 0 along the discrete time index. Hence, the **absorption state is 0 since we are looking for the state where we have no more coins showing tails left** Using this, I have the following matrix but don't know how to get P(X=1) from it

$\begin{matrix} 
\hdashline 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
                1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
                1/4 & 1/2 & 1/4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                1/8 & 3/8 & 3/8 & 1/8 & 0 & 0 \\
                1/16 & 1/4 & 3/8 & 1/4 & 1/16 & 0 \\
                1/32 & 5/32 & 5/16 & 5/16 & 5/32 & 1/32 \end{matrix}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my attempt to do it numerically, replacing state 1 as an absorbing state, since if the chain ever visits 1, then 1 is the last state visited before zero for sure. Got to give a health warning that I'm not 100% sure that this is an appropriate method :) :

```
M = matrix([[ 1.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ],
    [ 0.     ,  1.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ],
    [ 0.25   ,  0.5    ,  0.25   ,  0.     ,  0.     ,  0.     ],
    [ 0.125  ,  0.375  ,  0.375  ,  0.125  ,  0.     ,  0.     ],
    [ 0.0625 ,  0.25   ,  0.375  ,  0.25   ,  0.0625 ,  0.     ],
    [ 0.03125,  0.15625,  0.3125 ,  0.3125 ,  0.15625,  0.03125]])

p = matrix("0,0,0,0,0,1")

In [32]: print [round(i,3) for i in array(p * M**20)[0]]
[0.276, 0.724, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: what are the variables corresponding to 0.276 and 0.724?

Comment: I hope they represent the probability of reaching state 0 before 1, and the probability of reaching state 1 before 0. Starting in state 5.